# не удаётся получить данные из FireBase, хотя с тем же кодом в другом приложении данные поступают

Tags: firebase-database, firebase-android

Пишу приложение по обзору фильмов.
Решил использовать некоторые возможности FireBase, но прописав запросы, данные не приходят из FireBase. Никакие ошибки не возникают. Просто ничего не приходит.

Пробовал взять этот-же код с запросами и вставить в новое пустое приложение - и всё отлично работает (данные приходят из FireBase и записываются в неё.).
Возможно конфликт из-за БД Room или multidex - не знаю.

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tv_countOfAgreeUsers;            // текстовое поле для количества пользователей
private DatabaseReference refs_agreeUsers;        // ссылки по ветке "agreeusers"
private String key_agreeUsers = "agreeusers";     // ключ по ветке 'agreeusers'


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_gladevt);

    tv_countOfAgreeUsers = findViewById(R.id.tv_countOfAgreeUsers);

    
   //read data    (DATA has not been being red from  FDB)
    refs_agreeUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(key_agreeUsers);
    ValueEventListener vel_users = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            long countOfUsers = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            tv_countOfAgreeUsers.setText(String.format("%s", countOfUsers));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    };
    refs_agreeUsers.addValueEventListener(vel_users);

    
    //записываю данные, но они не записываются в БД     // write data   (NO DATA IS ADDED TO FDB     (data has not been being added to FDB))
    String userID = "2343432423423";
    UserClass user = new UserClass(userID);
    refs_agreeUsers.push().setValue(user);
}

public void onClick_showNumber(View view) {
    tv_countOfAgreeUsers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}


файл BuildGradle(Module)

multiDexEnabled true // добавли я т.к.вышла ошибка по dex
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'




def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
// optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"
// optional - Test helpers for LiveData
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"



def room_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"
// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"
// Test helpers
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"



// добавил я для firebase

// Import the Firebase BoM
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')

// Add the dependencies for the desired Firebase products
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


// из-за ошибки dex
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex: 2.0.1'


// Add the dependencies for the desired Firebase products
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

полностью переустановить BuildGradle(Module app).

алгоритм:

1. скопировать содержимое глючного BuildGradle(Module) в блокнот;
2. создать пустой проект, скопировать в буфер cодержимое BuildGradle(Мodul app)
3. вставить в свой проект вместо глючного BuildGradle и синхронизировать проект (просто синхронизируйте, ... не запуская сам проект на выполнение)

---

4. из блокнота взять свой глючный BuildGradlе и вернуть на место в свой проект
5. снова синхронизировать.

ps/
(неделю пропарился. ... Firebase спрашивать бесполезно)